# Arguments in syscall intercept using loadable kernel module seem to be broken

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

First post so I apologize for the possibly low quality explanation.

I was trying to write a loadable kernel module that does nothing but intercept syscalls to SYS_open, print the arguments to KERN_INFO and then forward the arguments to the real syscall.
The forwarding part seems to be working just fine, but I'm having issues with the printing, arguments seem to be broken, from the syscall interceptor function's perspective.

Following are the pointer to the real open syscall as well as the interceptor definition.

```
asmlinkage int (*real_open) (const char __user *, int, umode_t);

asmlinkage int fake_open(const char __user *filename, int flags, umode_t mode)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "interceptor: open() with flags = %d\n", flags);

    return real_open(filename, flags, mode);
}
```

This is the syscall I'm testing:

```
syscall(SYS_open, argv[1], 3187236);
```

Which leads to the following call, according to strace:

```
open("test", O_RDONLY|O_TRUNC|__O_SYNC|O_LARGEFILE|O_PATH|FASYNC|0x24) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

And the information printed by the interceptor:

```
[18191.407899] interceptor: open() with flags = 0
```

As you can see, the flags argument is equal to 0, even though I passed 3187236 as flags.
What's even weirder, the real open syscall seems to have no issue in dealing with the arguments.

Any kind of help is appreciated since I'm pretty much stuck here.

Here's the full module code in case it's of any help:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/futex.h>

#include <linux/highmem.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>

/*

SYSCALL_DEFINE3(open, const char __user *, filename, int, flags, umode_t, mode)

*/

unsigned long long *sys_call_table = (unsigned long long*) 0xffffffffaf800260;    //sudo cat /proc/kallsyms | grep sys_call_table         (/boot/System.map)

asmlinkage int (*real_open) (const char __user *, int, umode_t);

asmlinkage int fake_open(const char __user *filename, int flags, umode_t mode)
{
    printk("interceptor: open() with flags = %d\n", flags);

    return real_open(filename, flags, mode);
}


//make the memory page writable
int make_rw(unsigned long long address)
{
    unsigned int level;
    pte_t *pte = lookup_address(address, &level);

    if(pte->pte & ~_PAGE_RW)
        pte->pte |= _PAGE_RW;

    return 0;   
}

//make the memory page read only
int make_ro(unsigned long long address)
{
    unsigned int level;
    pte_t *pte = lookup_address(address, &level);

    pte->pte &= ~_PAGE_RW;

    return 0;
}


static int __init init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Attempting to install hook.\n");

    make_rw((unsigned long long) sys_call_table);

    real_open = (void*) sys_call_table[__NR_open];
    sys_call_table[__NR_open] = (unsigned long long) fake_open;

    make_ro((unsigned long long) sys_call_table);

    return 0;   //no error
}

static void __exit clean(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Uninstalling hook.\n");

    make_rw((unsigned long long) sys_call_table);

    sys_call_table[__NR_open] = (unsigned long long) real_open;

    make_ro((unsigned long long) sys_call_table);
}

module_init(init);
module_exit(clean);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: Same behaviour with different values for flags? Can you access the filename? What kernel / standard library version?

Comment: Intercepting system calls never works. It has been discussed *ad nauseam*. Stop trying. [Query regarding kernel modules intercepting system call](https://lists.kernelnewbies.org/pipermail/kernelnewbies/2017-July/018091.html) on the kernel newbies mailing list.

Comment: @DanielJour No behaviour change regardless of value passed to flags argument. Filename pointer seems to point to random null data, and copy_from_user() doesn't do anything either. Kernel version is 5.3.7, gcc version is 9.2.0.

Comment: @jww Thanks for your contribution. I do agree that syscall interception is a bad idea in most cases. Regardless of their possible use scenario, the issue is still present and I really want to at least understand what is going on. Most sources I've read tackle syscall interception the same way I am, but I cannot find anything regarding my issue.

Comment: What architecture is this? x86_64, or something else?

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, x86_64.

Comment: Tested the code on another machine with linux kernel 4.15.0 and gcc 7.4.0 and it works just fine... Any input about how I would go about debugging stuff like this?

Comment: At least on x86_64, it appears that `sys_call_table[n]` is not called with separate arguments, but rather with a single argument which is a pointer to `struct pt_regs`.  It looks like there are some automatically generated wrappers that unpack the arguments and call the ordinary `sys_open()` function.  See for instance `asm/syscalls.h` and friends.  This was added for version 4.17 so I think you are looking at some old information.

Comment: Relevant code: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/510c9788991c58827373bca719d8cffa4d65f846/arch/x86/entry/common.c#L294

Comment: @NateEldredge Yep, that was it. Finally fixed it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
**Kernel version 4.17 and up requires parameters to be passed through a pt_regs struct. Previous code was good up to 4.16.**

```
asmlinkage long (*real_open) (const struct pt_regs *);

asmlinkage long fake_open(const struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    printk("interceptor: open() with flags = %ld\n", regs->si);

    return real_open(regs);
}
```

**More information**: https://github.com/milabs/khook/issues/3

Thanks for everyone who contributed in the comments!